# JSX - Render code stored in array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have a question.  If  I store JSX code in an array and it contains

```
<Accordion uniqId={'addAsset'} 
{...this.props} 
 singleOpen={true} > 
    <AccordionSection title=Asset Summary - Mandatories 
     noFunctions=12 
     noFunctionsDone=0 
     validated={true} 
     required={true} 
     openByDefault={true} > 
         <p>RenderInput</p>
         <p>RenderInput</p>
    </AccordionSection> 
</Accordion>
```

I return it from the function that builds it. The function parse().

```
return JSX;
```

And try to use it in my component like so.

```
  render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>
                    {this.parse(this.props.form)}
                </div>
        );
    }
```

It is not doing what I expect!  It is just rendering the code as a string to the screen.  How do I get it to render for real!?

**EDIT**
Full parse() inside component

```
//---------------------------------
class SmartForm extends Component {

// this is a form description parser and renderer.
// it takes the description of a form in JSON format,
// passed in as a prop.


    //-----------------
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    }

    //-------------------
    formStart(formType) {

        // each page type in a single or multi page for will have it's own
        // format that has been decreed by the PROPS required by each
        // form initiation.

        let JSX = [];

        console.log('formStart');
        switch(formType) {
            case 'accordion':
                JSX.push("<Accordion");
                JSX.push("  uniqId={'addAsset'}");
                JSX.push("  {...this.props}");
                JSX.push("  singleOpen={true} >");
                console.log('formStart = accordion');
                break;
            case 'workflow':
                break;
            case 'modal':
                break;
            case 'normal':
                break;
        }   
        console.log(JSX);
        return(JSX);
    }

    //-----------------
    formEnd(formType) {

        // each page type in a single or multi page for will have it's own
        // format that has been decreed by the PROPS required by each
        // form initiation.

        let JSX = [];

        switch(formType) {
            case 'accordion':
                JSX.push("</Accordion>");
                break;
            case 'workflow':
                break;
            case 'modal':
                break;
            case 'normal':
                break;
        }    
        return(JSX);
    }

    //-------------------
    pageStart(pageType) {

        // each page type in a single or multi page for will have it's own
        // format that has been designed by the operations management
        // and the CSS designers.

        let JSX = [];

        switch(pageType) {
            case 'accordion':
                       JSX.push(" <AccordionSection ");
                       JSX.push(" title=Asset Summary - Mandatories ");
                       JSX.push(" noFunctions=12");
                       JSX.push(" noFunctionsDone=0");
                       JSX.push(" validated={true} ");
                       JSX.push(" required={true} ");
                       JSX.push(" openByDefault={true} > ");
                break;
            case 'workflow':
                break;
            case 'modal':
                break;
            case 'normal':
                break;

        }
        return(JSX);
    }

    //-----------------
    pageEnd(pageType) {

        // each page type in a single or multi page for will have it's own
        // format that has been designed by the operations management
        // and the CSS designers.

        let JSX = [];

        switch(pageType) {
            case 'accordion':
                JSX.push("</AccordionSection>");
                break;
            case 'workflow':
                break;
            case 'modal':
                break;
            case 'normal':
                break;

        }
        return(JSX);
    }

    //-----------
    parse(form) {

        // this is the main form parser
        // the DESCRIPTION of the for comes into this
        // component as a JSON TREE
        // this parser traverses the tree and constructs the
        // JSX code to be rendered in the calling CONTAINER
        // these few lines of code handle ALL of the forms,
        // in ALL formats, in ALL of the application, from
        // now, until the end of days.

        let JSX = [];                                                       // container for the JSX to be rendered
        let element = '';                                                   // outside field element of form
        let pageElement = "";                                               // page elements
        let fieldElement = "";                                              // each of the field objects in the page
        let formFormat = '';                                                // snatch this value out of tree as we traverse

        console.log(form);

        for (element in form) {                                             // traverse the primary elements
            console.log('----------------------');
            console.log(element);
            switch(element) {                                               // which element are we on?
                case 'formName':                                            // we don't care about the name in here
                    break;
                case 'format':                                              // we DO care about the format!
                    console.log(form.format);
                    JSX.push(...this.formStart(form.format));               // handle the form intro JSX
                    break;
                case 'pages':
                    for (pageElement in form.pages) {                       // iterate for 1..N pages
                        JSX.push(...this.pageStart(form.format));           // depending on the format, each new page gets unique JSX
                        console.log(form.pages[pageElement]);               // debugging
                        let pageArray = form.pages[pageElement];            // Pitman
                        for (fieldElement in pageArray.fields) {            // iterate down the LIST
                            console.log(fieldElement);                      // debugging
                            let fields = pageArray.fields[fieldElement];    // Pitman again
                            JSX.push(...SmartRender(fields));               // and process the field - this does a LOT of work as well!
                        }
                    JSX.push(...this.pageEnd(form.format));                 // finish THIS page
                    }
            }
        }
        JSX.push(...this.formEnd(form.format));                             // finish off the rendering
        console.log(JSX);                                                   // debugging
        return(JSX);                                                        // send back the code for rendering
    }

    //--------
    render() {
        let code = this.parse(this.props.form);
        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>
                    {code.map(function(line, key) {
                        return line;
                        }
                    )}
                </div>
        );
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
export default SmartForm;

//-----------------   EOF -------------------------------------------------
```

** SECOND EDIT **

```
//--------------------------
export const assetForm  = {
                            "formName": "assetCreateEdit",
                            "format": "accordion",
                            "pages":
                                [{
                                    "pageID": "1",
                                    "title": "Asset Summary - Mandatories",
                                    "fields":
                                        [
                                            {   
                                                "name": "testname",
                                                "altName": "",
                                                "visible": true,
                                                "groupVisibility": "public",
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "component": "input",
                                                "label": "Test Smart Input",
                                                "placeholder": "Some default Value",
                                                "required": "required",
                                                "validated": false,
                                                "data": []
                                            },
                                            {   
                                                "name": "password",
                                                "altName": "",
                                                "visible": true,
                                                "groupVisibility": "public",
                                                "type": "password",
                                                "component": "input",
                                                "label": "Test Smart Input",
                                                "placeholder": "Password",
                                                "required": "required",
                                                "validated": false,
                                                "data": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "pageID": "2",
                                    "title": "Asset Images - Mandatories",
                                    "fields":
                                        [
                                            {   
                                                "name": "testname",
                                                "altName": "",
                                                "visible": true,
                                                "groupVisibility": "public",
                                                "type": "imageDrop",
                                                "component": "imageDropbox",
                                                "label": "Test Image Dropbox",
                                                "placeholder": "",
                                                "required": "required",
                                                "validated": false,
                                                "optiminstic": "optomisticPrevire",
                                                "data": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                 }
                                ]
                            };
```

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: not sure i understand, do you have a codepen perhaps?

Comment: It is a little complex to give it a code pen.

Comment: hmm, can you provide the full `Parse` function

Comment: Sure.  Gimmie a sec and I'll stick it somewhere public.  Thanks

Comment: I stuck the component in my original edit.

Comment: why are you rendering the code as strings?

Comment: Probably because I don't know what I am doing!  Just learning React.  The idea is for the parser to construct jsx code to be rendered.

Comment: I have excellent news for you lol, you can return JSX directly.... ill post an example.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to render JSX as a string, you can simply return normal JSX as follows...

You should be able to refactor your code like this.

```
//---------------------------------
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            sampleArray: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
        };

        this.renderExample = this.renderExample.bind(this); // bind this to class method
    }

    renderExample() {
        const { sampleArray } = this.state;

        sampleArray.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div className={item} key={item}>
                    {item}
                </div>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                {this.renderExample()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

/*
This would render the following JSX
-----------------------------------
<div id="container">
    <div className="item 1">
        "item 1"
    </div>
    <div className="item 2">
        "item 2"
    </div>
    <div className="item 3">
        "item 3"
    </div>
    <div className="item 4">
        "item 4"
    </div>
</div>
-------------------------------------
HOPE THIS HELPS =]
*/
```

Comment: I thank you.  However, my parser is creating more than data items, or it is trying to!  To use your analogy, my parser is producing:

sampleArray: ["<div className=somethingComputed>",
                       "<"Field component='input' name='name' value=''>",
                       "</div>"];
The parser reads a JSON object that DESCRIBES a form.  So I don't know before hand the structure of the form until I parse it. Cheers!

Comment: post a sample of the json might look like

Comment: Up in my original.  That is the description of the contents of a form.  The structure of the form changes through various mechanisms so I want to produce the interior of a form from a description file.  I hope that makes sense.  The next object may have a dozen different fields.

Comment: you should still be able to do all the checking you were doing before but instead of building an array of strings, return JSX

Comment: Ta! :-)  The question is how?
In the parser - p-code
    if the formType == "accordion" then
       the start of the output is
          <Accordion name={name} >
    else the start of the output is
       <fieldset name={name}>

[constuct the rest of the form ...]

    if the formType == "accordion" then
      the form end should be </Accordion>
   else
    the form end is </Fieldset>